# Rspec how to set an expectation on the superclass for an overridden method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I've got a model class that overrides update_attributes:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def update_attributes(attributes)
    if super(attributes)
      #do some other cool stuff
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to figure out how to set an expectation and/or stub on the super version of update_attributes to make sure that in the success case the other stuff is done. Also I want to make sure that the super method is actually being called at all.

Here's what I have tried so far (and it didn't work, of course):

```
describe "#update_attributes override" do
  it "calls the base class version" do
    parameters = Factory.attributes_for(:foo)
    foo = Factory(:foo, :title => "old title")
    ActiveRecord::Base.should_receive(:update_attributes).once
    foo.update_attributes(parameters)
  end
end
```

This doesn't work, of course:

```
Failure/Error: ActiveRecord::Base.should_recieve(:update_attributes).once
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `should_recieve' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`update_attributes` is an instance method, not a class method, so you cannot stub it directly on `ActiveRecord::Base` with rspec-mocks, as far as I know.  And I don't think that you should: the use of `super` is an implementation detail that you shouldn't be coupling your test to.  Instead, its better to write examples that specify the behavior you want to achieve.  What behavior do you get from using `super` that you wouldn't get if `super` wasn't used?

As an example, if this was the code:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def update_attributes(attributes)
    if super(attributes)
      MyMailer.deliver_notification_email
    end
  end
end
```

...then I think the interesting pertinent behavior is that the email is only delivered if there are no validation errors (since that will cause `super` to return true rather than false).  So, I might spec this behavior like so:

```
describe Foo do
  describe "#update_attributes" do
    it 'sends an email when it passes validations' do
      record = Foo.new
      record.stub(:valid? => true)
      MyMailer.should_receive(:deliver_notification_email)
      record.update_attributes(:some => 'attribute')
    end

    it 'does not sent an email when it fails validations' do
      record = Foo.new
      record.stub(:valid? => false)
      MyMailer.should_receive(:deliver_notification_email)
      record.update_attributes(:some => 'attribute')
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `should_recieve` with `should_receive`.

Comment: HA! yeah, that would have helped a bit. Good catch. I before E except after C. Sheesh.